# How can I filter out questions that have been answered by a user?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a small quiz/test engine with AJAX, PHP, and MySQL. All of the data (questions, answers, etc.) is stored in a database.

The issue that I am having is that I can't find out how to filter out the questions that have been answered by the user that is logged in, therefore resulting in questions being repeated and a never ending quiz/test.

When you click the "next question" button, an AJAX request is sent to `submit_answer.php` which submits the answer (adds row to `user_answers` table) and it also sends a request to `get_question.php` which then returns JSON of the question information (question, answers, etc.) but I can't seem to get it to not select questions that have been answered (questions in the `user_answers` table). Here is what I've got right now:

```
$question = mysql_query("SELECT *, q.id qid, q.question question_text 
                         FROM questions q, user_answers ua
                         WHERE q.id != ua.question_id 
                           AND ua.test_id = $test 
                           AND ua.user_id = $_SESSION[userid] 
                         ORDER BY rand() 
                         LIMIT 1");

$q = mysql_fetch_assoc($question);
```

This query is supposed to select the questions that have the `test_id` of the current test, has the `user_id` as the current user, and not in the `user_answers` table. But apparently, I'm just not doing it right.

You can see the entire `get_question.php` file here: http://pastebin.com/Td6mqp49

#### Edit:

Here are my table structures as requested by @MadaraUchiha:

`questions`

[image]

`user_answers`

[image]

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Also, how does your table structure look like?

Comment: most mysql have an equivalent mysqli. You don'T have to do prepared statement. THings like mysqli_fetch_assoc exist..

Comment: @MadaraUchiha See my question, I added the table structures for `questions` and `user_answers`

Comment: @Nathan: You don't **have** to use prepared statements on this query (as it contains no repetition and no user input). But the ext/mysql function should die.

Comment: @Nathan, nevermind, I think Gordon got it.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha So you think I could use replace `mysql_query` with `mysqli_query` and then do some different code for the opening of the connection, or do I have to include more code on each query? I don't really see the benefit of using `mysqli_*` rather than `mysql_*` functions when `mysql_*` is working just fine for me.

Comment: @Nathan: Please read the linked question, http://bit.ly/phpmsql. The mere fact that you won't be able to use prepared statements even if you wanted to, is reason enough to move.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Oh okay. So I can still use queries like above with the `mysqli_*` functions, right?

Comment: @Nathan: That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a left outer join between the questions to the user_answers tables.

The final query looks like:

```
SELECT *, q.id qid, q.question question_text 
FROM questions q left outer join
     user_answers ua
     on q.id = ua.question_id and
        ua.test_id = $test and
        ua.user_id = $_SESSION[userid] 
WHERE ua.user_id is null
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *, q.id qid, q.question question_text 
FROM questions q
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT TRUE
    FROM user_answers ua
    WHERE ua.question_id = q.id
    AND ua.test_id = $test 
    AND ua.user_id = $_SESSION[userid]
)
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 1
```

The reason why your query wasn't working is that `q.id != ua.question_id` will match as long as there is at least one answer that doesn't belong to the question - *any* answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM
questions q
WHERE 
q.id NOT IN (
    SELECT question_id as id
    FROM user_answers
    WHERE ua.test_id = $test AND ua.user_id = $_SESSION[userid]
)
```

On a side note, make sure you properly sanitize the data before passing to the SQL.

Comment: BTW, I do sanitize the data. Take a look at `get_question.php` here: http://pastebin.com/Td6mqp49

Comment: Great to see :), I am bit paranoid about it.. I usually use single quotes even if it is INT, so AND ua.test_id = $test would be AND ua.test_id = '$test'.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a little paranoid as well sometimes. Even though it's not actual user input it still must be sanitized if it is coming from the client as someone could manually send an AJAX request with some SQL injection code as one of the GET variables if they wanted to.

Comment: @Nathan, if you use prepared queries, as Madara Uchiha suggested, then you won't have to worry about data sanitation. Also, @ xelber, using single quotes doesn't give you any benefit—I can simply include a ' character in my input to close your quote and jump back into the SQL.